# MathJax rendering unexpected character on android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, mathjax

I'm Trying to render **MathJax** on android app using **webview**. But unexpected character is showing after rendering the given html string.

Here is my code

```
public void renderHtml(WebView w, String data){
    w.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    w.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    String finalData = data;
  

    w.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,mathJaxScript+"<span style=\" margin:0px; top:0px; \"><math display='inline-block'>"+data+"</math></span>",
            "text/html","utf-8",null);
}
```

Here Is **MathJax**  configurations to render.

```
public String mathJaxScript="<script type='text/javascript' "
        + "src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML'"
        + "id=\"MathJax-script\" async"
        + "></script>"
        +"<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
        + "MathJax.Hub.Config({ "
        +"skipStartupTypeset: false,"
        + "showMathMenu: false, "
        +"tex2jax: { inlineMath: [[\"$\", \"$\"]],displayMath:[[\"$$\", \"$$\"]] },"
        +"mtextFontInherit: true,"
        +"CommonHTML: {scale: 100},"
        + "});" +
        "  \"  MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook('End', () => {\\n\" +\n" +
        "            \"        window.hubReady.next();\\n\" +\n" +
        "            \"        window.hubReady.complete();\\n\" +\n" +
        "            \"      });\\n\"" +
        "</script>"
        + "<span id='math'></span>" ;
```

Here is the **output** after render

[image]

It is working fine in Android version 10 & 9 but can't render it in android 7.
If you have any ideas on how to fix this, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason to set the text encoding to `iso-8859-15`? I, too, faced this issue while rendering HTML files(EULA and privacy settings for a set of languages) which were given to me by UX team with non-UTF8 text encoded. I had to manually open each file in Notepad++ and convert the encoding to `UTF-8` to get it working. Could you please try setting the encoding to **UTF-8** and check?

Comment: I already tried the **UTF-8**, but still I got  the same result. @jay

Comment: Please remove the call, `w.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("iso-8859-15");`. You are setting this one and again calling `w.loadDataWithBaseURL` with `utf-8` argument.

Comment: I removed the call. Thanks @jay

Comment: IMO, you should be calling the method [WebView#loadData()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method as you don't want to open a script hosted on a URL; rather rendering the page from locally configured html string.

Answer (score 0):

After some exploring, I found that in **loadDataWithBaseURL** method, the encoding parameter is not working (i don't know why). When I replaced this

```
w.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,mathJaxScript+"<span style=\" margin:0px; top:0px; \"><math display='inline-block'>"+data+"</math></span>",
        "text/html","utf-8",null);
```

with

```
loadDataWithBaseURL(null,mathJaxScript+"<span style=\" margin:0px; top:0px; \"><math display='inline-block'>"+data+"</math></span>","text/html; charset=utf-8",null,null);
```

it works and solves the issue

if you see these two method, you will find that if we pass ***charset=utf-8*** in **mimetype** parameter and ***null*** in **charset** parameter, then it will render perfectly in webview.
And thanks @Jay, for helping